# HttpsURLConnection.getInputStream works fine in Eclipse but server returns response code 503 after code is exported and run from command line

Tags: java, eclipse, inputstream, http-status-code-503

I use Eclipse and occasionally export my program and run it from the command line. The functionality is exactly the same except this one thing:

`HttpsURLConnection` reads some data from a website. This works fine when I run the code from Eclipse. However, after I export my code as Runnable JAR, this part of the program does not work: I get a

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503
```

Here is the method that triggers this error:

```
private List<Event> parse(final String url) throws IOException {
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)u.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Windows NT 6.1)");
        inputStream = con.getInputStream();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final String page
        = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toString(inputStream, java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
    inputStream.close();
    ...
}
```

Please note that my program only visits this website once. It does not "harass" the server...

Comment: What is the URL that you are hitting?

Comment: @aksappy The URL is https://www.forexfactory.com/calendar

Comment: I have no issues with the code that you just pasted. Try adding more logs and see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced `java` in the command line with `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin\java.exe"` and now it works.

[I found out that's what Eclipse was doing by going to Project → Properties → Run/Debug Settings → Edit → Show Command Line].

I am not sure where exactly the plain `java` I was using before was pointing - and at this point, I don't intend to investigate.